# Searchable tagged tables in lua?

Tags: search, data-structures, lua, lua-table

So I need to search tables based on a number of tags.

It needs to create lists of matches based on the number of tags.
So if we had a match with 4 tags that would be a list, 3 tags another list, 2 another.

How would you implement this with lua tables?

I don't want too complicated things,if there is a library or a interface with a database that is not complicated to setup, fine.

But if not I can accept a native solution at the cost of speed and memory.

What i mean by tags is this

Lets say we have table

T[1] ={cat,mouse bat, fly, car, airplane,glider}

A few of those terms like the bat,fly,airplane,glider will have a tag flyable.

Another tag could be machine for the car and airplane.

Another tag is animals: cat,mouse,bat,fly

So if you search with both tags flyable + machine you get airpalne
If you search animal+flyable you get bat and fly.

So what I need is a structure to contain this tag information that lets me easily search.

Comment: What are tags? I don't get what you mean. Use code to explain what's the input and what's the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Sets might be the type of data structure you are looking for. Have a look at Set as explained in the [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.1.html) book.

Comment: Intersection is the thing I need but I'm not sure about its comparison function and making everything true.

Answer (score 1):

```
function findtable(table,value)
        for k,v in pairs(table) do
                if (v == value) or (k == value) then
                        return true
                end
        end
        return false
end

function tagged_flyable(value)
    local flyable_table = {'bat','fly','airplane','glider'}
    if(findtable(flyable_table,value) == true) then
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
end

function tagged_animals(value)
    local animals_table = {'cat','mouse','bat','fly'}
    if(findtable(animals_table,value) == true) then
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
end

function tagged_machines(value)
    local machines_table = {'car', 'airplane'}
    if(findtable(machines_table,value) == true) then
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
end

-- main process
local T_1 = {'cat','mouse', 'bat', 'fly', 'car', 'airplane', 'glider'}
local search_results = {}
-- search for tag: flyable+machine
for i=1,table.getn(T_1) do
    if(tagged_machines(T_1[i]) and tagged_flyable(T_1[i])) then
        table.insert(search_results, T_1[i])
        print("found :", T_1[i])
    end
end


-- search for tag: flyable+animals
search_results = {}
for i=1,table.getn(T_1) do
    if(tagged_animals(T_1[i]) and tagged_flyable(T_1[i])) then
        table.insert(search_results, T_1[i])
        print("found :", T_1[i])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be a table of tags, plus two results tables. Table of tags:

```
T = {cat={"animal", "legs"}, bat={"animal", "wings"}, ...}
```

Result table is just regular table of which objects have a certain tag:

```
res1 = get(T, "wings")
print(res1) -- prints cat bat plane 
res2 = get(T, "machine")
print(res2) -- prints car train plane
```

Then a function that finds intersection of both results:

```
bothTags = getIntersection(res1,res2)
```

The getIntersection() just has to loop over first table res1 and test if res2[itemFromFirstTable] is nil, if not then you have an item in both tables.